# Vector of maps with custom comparator

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a `vector` of `map`s. Each `map` has a different comparator.

Here is what I have tried:-

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<vector>

template <class T>
struct head {
  virtual bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const = 0;
};

template <class T>
struct greater: head<T> {
  bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {return x>y;}
};

template <class T>
struct less: head<T> {
  bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {return x<y;}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::map<int, int, head<int>>> mp;
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting an error that `my operator()` is pure virtual in **head**.

Please tell me what is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: If a class has a pure virtual function then you can't create an object of that class. You can't create objects of an abstract class.

Comment: @Ch3steR: Thanks, yes you are right about that. Please suggest a solution. Defining the `operator()` in **head** is not gonna solve my problem.

Comment: std::vector<std::map<int, int, less<int>>> mp;

Comment: @nevilad: That way I can only insert maps with a `less<int>` comparator. Not any other map. I am trying to `push_back` maps with different comparators.

Answer (score 1):

You need a single comparator type that works for all your vectors.  Like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct comp {
  comp(bool gt) : do_greater(gt) {} 
  bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const
  {
    return do_greater ? x > y : x < y;
  }
  bool do_greater;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::map<int, int, comp<int>>> mp;
  mp.emplace_back(false); // first map uses less-than
  mp.emplace_back(true); // first map uses greater-than
}
```

That is, the choice of comparison function needs to be driven by the state initialized in each std::map constructor.  That single `?:` branch is probably better for performance than calling a virtual method every time, too.

Comment: Thanks for solution. So if I have a number of comparators then I have to declare an `enum class` (instead of **do_greater** ) giving name to each operation I want to apply. After that on every `push_back` operation in `operator()`  a `switch`  case over the `enums` will execute based upon tye of comparison I need. Right?